# How to create a raster delineating all drainage basins using pysheds python

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, rasterio, numpy

I am going through the tutorial of "Pysheds" available in the following website

https://www.hatarilabs.com/ih-en/elevation-model-conditioning-and-stream-network-delimitation-with-python-and-pysheds-tutorial

Corresponding to all the steps mentioned in this tutorial, similar steps can be done in ArcMap (under Spatial Analyst --> Hydrology Tool).

Now the issue is I want to know is there any function available in Python Pysheds library to delineate all the drainage basins available in the DEM (after generation of flow direction map from DEM) as it is there in ArcMap's "Basin" tool under Hydrology.

Comment: As far as I know, there is not. I wanted to do the same thing, but without much luck... One way to get the biggest catchment is to determine an accumulation map, get the indexes of the biggest value, and from those determine the catchment.

Comment: @Gevaert Joep. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: please update if you found something, I'd be interested.... I could post what I have up to now, but it's not a full solution...

Comment: Also interested in this.. So any code will help. Starting my own solution in the meantime

Answer (score 0):

Check the Whitebox geospatial python package (https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/manual/wbt_book/intro.html). It has an abundance of hydrological tools, e.g. for watershed and basin delineation.